# onBeforeRequest not triggering: expected 'object' but got 'array'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to let onBeforeRequest trigger but it doesn't trigger once.

The [background page console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension) displays an error:

> Invalid value for argument 1. Expected 'object' but got 'array'

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Blocker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Blocks all websites",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    console.log("TRIGGERED")
    return {cancel: true};
  },
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking"]);
```

What am I doing wrong or am I just expecting something onBeforeRequest isn't supposed to do? For example I expect the following:

1. I enter url into address bar
2. I press enter
3. onBeforeRequest triggers before website is shown
4. User gets message that website is blocked

Comment: Yes you're right, I get the following error: http://prntscr.com/ef6pij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription):

> In addition to specifying a callback function, **you have to specify a filter argument**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(info) {
        console.log(info);
        return {cancel: true};
    }, {
        urls: ['<all_urls>'],
    },
    ['blocking']
);
```